# Process anchor (hash) links with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hyperlink

Suppose I want to navigate to the following link:

```
http://www.mysite.com/feature#linktosection
```

The content of `http://www.mysite.com/feature` is loaded with jQuery ajax, so I cannot navigate to `#linktosection` until the ajax content has been loaded. Once it is loaded I need to navigate (maybe simulate a click) to `#linktosection`

This is my jQuery ajax call:

```
$('.changecontext-button').click(function()
{
    $.ajax({                                                           
        type: "POST",                                                  
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(data) {
            diffSection.html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            diffSection.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Do you know how to do this with jQuery?

An alternative could be parsing the href link and separate it into a *base url* and an *anchor url*. The, on success I could use a jQuery selector to get the anchor link and simulate a .click().

Is there any other better alternative, using jQuery or JavaScript?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I implemented it as follows:

```
$('.changecontext-button').click(function()
{
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({                                                           
        type: "POST",                                                  
        url: targetUrl,
        success: function(data) {
            diffSection.html(data);
            var anchor = getAnchor(targetUrl);
            if (anchor)
            {
                $(anchor).click();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                diffSection.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

...

```
function getAnchor(url)
{
    var index = url.lastIndexOf('#');
    if (index != -1)
        return url.substring(index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After your content has loaded:

```
$('a[name=' + window.location.hash + ']').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Put that code in your `success:` function. It takes `window.location.hash` (the bit in the URL after the hash part), then finds the anchor with that as its `name` attribute, and scrolls that element into view.

Comment: This does not work. window.location.hash returns empty, because my current URL does not have the anchor. The anchor is on the `$(this).attr('href')` property, so this solution is not valid for me.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well why not just do `window.location.hash = $('a',data).attr('name');` in your success function?

Answer (score 2):

This is, what works for me, when called after content is loaded:

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash
```